# How To Set Nvidia Overscan To Persistent After Reboot?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, x11

Stats of what I'm running:
TV:  HP MediaSmart TV 47" / OS:  Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit / Video Card:  Nvidia GeForce GT 220 / Video Driver:  Nvidia 260.19.06

When I first setup Ubuntu on this computer, after rebooting, the display resolution did not save.  I eventually fixed this by manually changing the display to the correct resolution in the xorg.conf file.  But I'm still unable to make the overscan setting persist after a reboot.  I've tried adding `nvidia-settings -l` to my autostart, but this does nothing.  I've also run the Nvidia Settings app with sudo and saved the changes, but this hasn't fixed the issue either.  I also noticed that there is a `.nvidia-settings-rc` file in my home directory that stores settings and there is a field `HTPC64:0.0/OverscanCompensation[DFP-1]=115` which IS correct, but this file and/or settings related to it don't seem to be saving because I still have to manually adjust the overscan in the Nvidia Settings after a reboot.  What else can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I'm really surprised nobody has replied to this yet because I've seen some amazingly intelligent people providing solutions on this site.  And I really don't think the problem I'm having is that difficult to figure out (at least for one of the pros).  For now, I have temporarily fixed this myself by adding a startup shortcut that runs the command: "nvidia-settings --assign 0/OverscanCompensation[DFP-1]=115".  However, this overscan issue is a problem before I ever login. I'd REALLY like to find a way to fix it before I'm even logged in.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this isn't too late. I ran across your question as I was having the same issue.
Open the nvidia-settings program. Set the overscan and various other goodies to your liking, then on the "nvidia-settings configuration" option in the left hand combo box, click on "Save Current Configuration" leave the default as `~/.nvidia-settings-rc`.

Then open your `~/.xinitrc` file, and add `nvidia-settings -l` to any line before the `exec ...` line or if/case structure containing it that points to your display manager of choice.

If you're unsure, somewhere near the top should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

On the latest driver, I had to use the GUI to setup my overscan in advanced mode

[image: nvidia settings]

Then I had to save the conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Then I had to copy the value of the meta mode, and write a script that does this:

**nvidia_tv_overscan_fix.sh**

```
# You can do this with a GUI now, from nvidia
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+720, HDMI-0: 1280x720 +0+0 {viewportin=1280x720, viewportout=1205x680+35+20}"
```

And run that on startup